# Not able to read in LIFO order using stack collection

Tags: java, generics, collections, stack, depth-first-search

I have created a double list as below.

```
List<Stack<Vertex>> allPaths = new ArrayList<Stack<Vertex>>();
```

When I collect all paths in the stack by doing DFS and try to print each stack using a for each iterator over stack collection , it prints in FIFO order.

```
void print(List<Stack<Vertex>> allPaths){
    for(Stack<Vertex> eachPath : allPaths){
          for(Vertex eachVertex: eachPath){
             System.out.print(eachVertex.name+" ");
           }
           System.out.println();
     } // end of stack iterator
} // end of print() function
```

So if the order in which each node visit gets completed is : 4->3->2->1 , it prints 4->3->2->1. What is the best collection to use here instead of stack to get LIFO order? It seems that there is a problem with the behavior of iterator returned over stack . It does not work in LIFO .

Comment: @EJP I already mentioned that in the question. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Stack` is a legacy class from Java 1.0 that extends `Vector`. `Vector` is a legacy class from Java 1.0 that is a synchronized version of the newer `ArrayList`.

Since `Vector` is backed by an array, pushing items to the stack means **appending** to the array (prepending would not perform well). Popping values means removing the **last** value from the array. As a stack, the functionality is correct, but the values are physically stored in the array in FIFO order.

As mentioned, they are legacy classes, and you shouldn't be using them, e.g javadoc of [`Stack`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) says:

> A more complete and consistent set of LIFO stack operations is provided by the `Deque` interface and its implementations, which should be used in preference to this class.

The javadoc of [`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) says:

> Deques can also be used as LIFO (Last-In-First-Out) stacks. This interface should be used in preference to the legacy `Stack` class. When a deque is used as a stack, elements are pushed and popped from the **beginning of the deque**.

So, iterating a `Deque` will see elements in LIFO order, while iterating a `Stack` will see elements in FIFO order. Both work correctly as a stack, though.

Answer (score -1):

use stack.pop

```
Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();
stack.push(4);
stack.push(3);
stack.push(2);
stack.push(1);
while (!stack.empty()) {
    System.out.println(stack.pop());
}
```